# Populating textfield with value that corresponds the selected value from a dropdown in PHP

Tags: php, dreamweaver

I have two fields in my mysql database which are ItemDescription and StockNo. ItemDescription populates the dropdown list. Upon selecting a value from the dropdown list, I would like to populate a textfield with the StockNo that corresponds the ItemDescription selected. I have no codes to show (aside from the form controls I inserted). I've heard this is possible through AJAX but I had no luck in finding a tutorial. Thank you in advance!

Also, I'm using Adobe Dreamweaver CS5 if that matters

Comment: You'd better refine your problem and question. But, I recommend you to check the following link: http://charlie.griefer.com/blog/2009/09/17/jquery-dynamically-adding-form-elements/

Comment: @mert now what I'm looking for right now but thanks! I have another problem and this is the solution!

Answer (score 0):

Place the number in the `value` attribute of your select's **options**:

```
<select id="dropdown">
    <option value="">Select an option …</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

Add an **input** to display the value:

```
<input type="text" id="value" />​
```

And make it work using **JavaScript**:

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("dropdown").onchange = function() {
        document.getElementById("value").value = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
    }
}
```

**Example (Fiddle):** http://jsfiddle.net/jhogervorst/nYADy/

Comment: Thank you! The code works fine, however I changed the value attribute of the options because my dropdown list is populated dynamically `<option value="<?php echo $row_RecordsetItem['Stock_No']?>"><?php echo $row_RecordsetItem['Dscription']?></option>`. Upon doing this the column Stock_No and Dscription gets the same value when I insert them on the table.

Comment: @GabrielAlain That's because `$row_RecordsetItem['Stock_No']` becomes the value of the `<select>`. You have to describe what `Stock_No` and `Dscription` are and what their relationship is, if you'd like me (or someone else) to have a look at it.

Comment: `Stock_No` and `Dscription` are from `tblSupplies`. I'm trying to make a Supplies Requisition module where the user for example, requests for folders or boxes of chalk. The user will fill out the requisition form, this contains the dynamic dropdownlist `Dscription` that will populate the `Stock_No`, `Quantity` available, and `Unit` dropdownlist. The record will be saved in `tblRIS` and is subject to  the admin's approval/rejection. Sorry, I don't know any better way to explain the relationship

Answer (score 0):

A simple basic solution may look like this....

```
<html>
<body>
Item Description <select id="ItemDescription" onchange="populate()">
<option value="Item1">Item1</option>`</select>
<br/>
Stock No <input type="text" id="StockNo" value=""/>
</body>
</html>
```

The JS Part.....

```
var xmlHttp;

function createXmlHttpRequest() {

     if(window.ActiveXObject)   {
         xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
     }
     else if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
         xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();      
     }
}

function populate() {

    createXmlHttpRequest(); 
var param = document.getElementById('ItemDescription').value;
    xmlHttp.open("GET", "http://localhost:9444/populate?itemdesc="+param, true);
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=handleStateChange;
    xmlHttp.send(null);    
 }


 function handleStateChange() {  

   if(xmlHttp.readyState==4) {   
       if(xmlHttp.status==200){         
         var stockNo = xmlHttp.responseText                       
         document.getElementById('StockNo').value = stockNo;                                              
    }
    else
        alert("Error Loading Page" + xmlHttp.status + xmlHttp.statusText);  
    }
 }
```

}

Comment: I got a popup window that says Error Loading Page0 when I selected from the dropdown list

Comment: If you post what you tried(both client and server codes)...it would be easy to tell...